# How do you perform a full text search via the Supabase Rest API?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, supabase

**Please can someone help provide the correct syntax for the request when making the full-text search query when making a REST API request?**

I've been looking at the Supabase docs, and I'm sure you can perform full-text searches generally:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/full-text-search
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/textsearch

However I'd like to perform the search by using the REST API. Here are a few examples of things I've tried so far:

1. `https://apikey.supabase.co/rest/v1/table?field=textSearch.%28"query"%29`
2. `https://apikey.supabase.co/rest/v1/table?field=to_tsquery.%28"query"%29`
3. `https://apikey.supabase.co/rest/v1/table?select=*&to_tsquery=field.query`
4. `https://apikey.supabase.co/rest/v1/table?select=*&to_tsquery=field.query`

P.S. I also attempted to use this type of format: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/1069

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supabase uses postgREST for their REST API. You can check the [postgREST documentation](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=text%20search#full-text-search) for this feature.

The fts filter has a number of options to support flexible textual queries, namely the choice of plain vs phrase search and the language used for stemming. Suppose that tsearch is a table with column my_tsv, of type tsvector. The following examples illustrate some possibilities:

```
GET /tsearch?my_tsv=fts(french).amusant HTTP/1.1

GET /tsearch?my_tsv=plfts.The%20Fat%20Cats HTTP/1.1

GET /tsearch?my_tsv=not.phfts(english).The%20Fat%20Cats HTTP/1.1
```

| Operator | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| fts | Full-Text Search using to_tsquery |
| plfts | Full-Text Search using plainto_tsquery |
| phfts | Full-Text Search using phraseto_tsquery |
| wfts | Full-Text Search using websearch_to_tsquery |

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to figure it out!